# Javascript vulnerability client-side

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

My concern is the next one.

I have a webpage (no ssl, `http://example.com`) where i implement a JavaScript routine that creates an IFrame to an https webpage (`https://secure.example.edu`). At this point is all ok, but if i want from the Chrome console i can change the iframe location(even if there is a same origin(X-FRAME-OPTIONS) policy) with a 302 Moved Permanently. So my question is, is posible that a user connects to `http://example.com` and without him knowing that iframe location changes? Without any code that does that on `example.com` or `secure.example.edu`.

L.E. As example imagine that on the secure.otherdomain.com i have a form where i submit my credit card. How can i assure the user that he is submitting his information to that domain and not other.

Comment: Sorry, but that's very unclear.  There's gonna be a lot of unhappy ceiling fans.  Can you explain specifically what your problem is?

Comment: I know my question is a little unclear, but as an example. Imagine that on that iframe i put my credit card. How safe is that? How can i be really sure that i'm not submitting my credit card information to other than secure.otherdomain.com?

Comment: Perhaps You should not put this kind of information in an iFrame. By the way, if there's a change in the iframe location, it will come from the client. You can't do anything about that.

Comment: @r4phG As i can see, my question got downvoted(And maybe no one else will respond). Maybe my fault for unclear question. Is not a problem, is more like a concern because i see pages like braintree or taxamo that use that option to get payment information trough a iframe to their webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i assure the user that he is submitting his information to that domain and not other.

You shouldn't assure the user of any such thing, because they might not be. The address bar says example.com and there is no indication of where the form comes from that the user can realistically verify. It could be an on-page element from example.com, an iframe pointing at otherdomain, or an iframe changed on the fly to point to an attacker server.

> i see pages like braintree or taxamo that use that option to get payment information trough a iframe to their webpage

Asking a user to enter credit card information into a page that isn't showing https in the address bar is obviously insecure and explicitly contrary to PCI-DSS compliance requirements for merchants.

Typically the merchant has their own certificate for their own site and the consumer is expected to trust the merchant, rather than trusting a third-party payment processing service as such. Merchants aren't supposed to be including cardholder data forms on non-https pages (by iframe or any other means), so if you've found some that are they need a kicking.

Comment: Ok, so is merchant obligation to put the payment information form on a ssl secure page.  But still, maybe is a dumb afirmation, i still can change the src of the iframe to the attacker server if that server is also ssl secure.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's never 100% sure.

But, you can do this: use a normal browser window instead of an iframe. The user can check the address in the address bar and the related certificate. By using iframes, this essential information is hidden for simple users.

Comment: Moreover most of payment platforms allow a redirection to your website after the payment is done (whether it failed or passed). I think you should you a proper page for your needs